# Is it legal to take advantage of my opponent's priority mistakes?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I attack with a creature with infect, and then my opponent tells me he won't block.

My intent is to use [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth) on my infect creature regardless of whether or not my opponent blocks.

HOWEVER, my opponent forgets that I have priority and goes straight for the [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt).

Now it seems as though my opponent has just made a game-play error by casting that bolt when he didn't have priority.  Is it legal for me to take advantage of that, and play Giant Growth in response, thus benefiting from the error?

Comment: You can always play instants in response to your opponent casting spells. (unless the spell they cast has split second)

Comment: @Matt not what I was asking.  I was asking whether it is legal to take advantage of my opponent's gameplay mistake when he skipped my priority

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9213/how-do-you-handle-fast-players-in-a-casual-setting-that-skip-priority

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your opponent attempting to cast Lightning Bolt when they don't have priority is a legal shortcut as outlined in the comprehensive rules:

> **716.1.** When playing a game, players typically make use of mutually understood shortcuts rather than explicitly identifying each game
>   choice (either taking an action or passing priority) a player makes.

and also:

> **716.1a** The rules for taking shortcuts are largely unformalized. As long as each player in the game understands the intent of each other
>   player, any shortcut system they use is acceptable.

Clearly your opponent's intent was to cast Lightning Bolt assuming you just planned to pass priority. Therefore, after your opponent has tried to cast Lightning Bolt, you have the option of either:

1. Telling your opponent that he doesn't have priority and forcing him to undo the casting of Lightning Bolt
2. Allow the shortcut to happen at which point you can still cast Giant Growth as you should now have priority

Yes, it is legal for you to cast Giant Growth in response to your opponent ignoring your priority.

#### Edit

Some people claim that only the player with priority can propose a shortcut. While the rules do state this, they also state that any shortcut method that is understood and unambiguous is acceptable. Since players in every magic game I have ever seen (including MTG pro tour and similar high level play) ignore their opponent's priority when moving from their upkeep to their draw phase it seems to me that this behavior should be acceptable during other phases as well. Players may also go into the declare attackers phase by just tapping some of their creatures effectively skipping their opponent's priority. This is fairly common and took me no more than about one minute to find [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Bq6_VXbqpng#t=1131s) example and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Bq6_VXbqpng#t=1910s) example. Skipping your opponent's priority in this manner is exactly the same as skipping it after they declared attackers so you can cast Lightning Bolt.

What is not okay is saying you are going to do something and then not actually doing it after your opponent decides to not respond to it. (I'm not really sure how this situation came up as it isn't in the original question, but some answers have addressed it)

Comment: Also, none of the conventional shortcut examples in section 4.2 of the Tournament rules includes a situation where a spell is cast without requesting priority first. Especially during the Combat step, the shortcuts I'm familiar with are: "declare attackers" "Blockers?" "Assign Damage", etc. I'm not a Judge, so I don't know whether casting spells without requesting priority is simply unwise or an infraction, but I don't think CR section 716 justifies it.

Comment: @ghoppe, Matt is correct. Consider the shortcut "Go." It means: "I propose we both pass priority until it is no longer my turn." Similarly, "I cast Lightning Bolt" is a shortcut for "I propose that you pass priority and I cast Lightning Bolt." Shortcuts can definitely include choices made by other players, such as the choice to pass priority.

Comment: Umm, okay... I guess you could argue that, but since I can find no other way to interpret someone casting a spell when they don't have priority than them proposing that I pass priority and then they cast their spell, I can't see how there could be any confusion about the shortcut.

Comment: although really he didn't have the right to do so, unless he proposed the shortcut before declaring blockers, as only the player with priority can propose a shortcut through 716.

Comment: Here I thought I was being overly pedantic, but this has turned into an interesting debate. The issue for me is that simply declaring a spell isn't universally understood to be a shortcut for "we agree you pass priority first, yeah?" There are many examples of shortcuts in the tournament rules which would be irrelevant if this "master shortcut" were in force. In other words, simply declaring a spell when you don't have priority (or implied priority through words like "go" "combat damage?") is a misplay, not a shortcut.

Comment: If you don't interpret someone trying to cast a spell when they don't have priority as them suggesting that you first pass priority then they cast the spell, then what do you interpret it as? Can you provide some of those examples?

Comment: We're talking about the meaning of the word "shortcut" in the rules and the mutually agreed shortcuts which speed up the game. I interpret it as a mistake, clearly.

Comment: @Matt So in fact, per the rules, assuming an implied shortcut of 'declare no blockers, you pass priority, I lightning bolt, it resolves', it is actually REQUIRED that either the first three steps occur as written, or the attacking player performs an action when they are given priority in the declare blockers step.

Comment: Either the first steps must occur as listed, or the other player must interrupt it at any point where they would have priority.

Comment: @LK2, [Asked](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75842/29622687/NAP_suggesting_a_shortcut) on Wizard's Rules Q&A forum for MTG.

Comment: Hello commenters!  I'm deleting much of the back and forth above.  Please upvote which ever answer you feel is useful.  Submit your own answer if you can't get behind one of the answers already here.  Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami The question you asked on Wizard's Rules Q&A doesn't really represent the same situation as was discussed here. That said, I believe the discussion that resulted indicates my original answer is in fact correct.

Comment: @Matt, I believe they proved the opposite. I've added an answer.

Comment: About @Matt's edit. He's right it's convention for players to not worry about priority during the upkeep, but in games I've seen and played, the opposite happens during combat and each step is usually explicitly handled: "Declare attackers?" "go" "attack with these" "No blockers" "combat damage?" [Here's](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/article/20071109a) an interesting article on wizards.com about shortcut guidelines.

Comment: @ghoppe That may be how you play, but it took me very little time to find the two examples I just added to my answer of high level players skipping their opponent's priority when declaring attackers.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but I feel like it needs some citation from the MTR to really be complete.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. The rules don't say anything that's understood and unambiguous is acceptable, it merely says it has to be understood and unambiguous to be acceptable. It also says it has to the the turn of the player with priority to be acceptable.

Comment: @ikegame umm, yes they do `716.1a The rules for taking shortcuts are largely unformalized. As long as each player in the game understands the intent of each other player, any shortcut system they use is acceptable.`

Answer (score 2):

While I initially believed Matt was correct, it was pointed out (by LJ2?) that one cannot create a shortcut if one doesn't have priority.

> 716.2a At any point in the game, **the player with priority** may suggest a shortcut [...]

As such, your opponent is merely requesting priority, leaving you the following two options:

1. Tell your opponent that he doesn't have priority, preventing him from actually casting the Lightning Bolt at this time. (Any action he already took would be rolled back.)
2. Acquiesce his request and give up priority. Since no shortcut was proposed, he's not required to follow up with Lightning Bolt or he could change his choice of target, but he must follow up with an action (other than passing) according to the Tournament Rules. (If he doesn't, the game rolls back to when you had priority.)

So, you have the option of casting your spell before his Lightning Bolt, in response to it, or even after it resolves.

Comment: As an aside, your opponent should have waited for you to pass priority which you could have done explicitly or implicitly by assigning damage.

Comment: You can't say you are going to cast something and then not cast it (unless you cannot cast it due to not being able to pay the cost, or any other reason that would prevent you from legally casting the spell)

Comment: @Matt, Why not? (Rule #?) To my knowledge, there's nothing that says you can't. The only time someone is bound to do something they said they were going to do is if they proposed a shortcut and the other players accepted that part of the shortcut. The Lightning Bolt caster could not have proposed a shortcut since he did not have priority, and he's not bound by a shortcut someone else proposed.

Comment: From a judging perspective, we basically have to either treat this as understood player communication where B is proposing he cast LB next time it's his priority and is bound to it if A does not want to take an action, or else we start handing out infractions to B for a game rules violation every time this happens.  That is absurdly impractical to consider it a rules violation every time someone tosses down an instant before their opponent explicitly passes priority.  If both players understand the intent it's fine.

Comment: If we allow the 'take back' we also get constantly bogged down into cheating investigations to determine if B is "faking" spells to fish for information about A's hand.

Comment: @Affe, B is not allowed to propose since he doesn't have priority. /// Nothing is taken back since B never started casting it. // Absolutely no information was gathered from A. All A did was give up priority.

Comment: @ikegami when A allows B to cast the spell A is essentially saying he isn't going to counter it. Consider the situation where B has 2 big creatures x and y and A may have a counter. B wants to cast x without it getting countered so he plays y in an attempt to get A to cast his counter. When A doesn't counter it B then takes it back so he can instead cast x. That is most certainly not legal even if I can't cite a specific rule. In your example A gave up priority under the assumption that B was going to cast something he could respond to. There is a rule in the Tournament rules covering this.

Comment: @Matt, "When A allows B to cast the spell A is essentially saying he isn't going to counter it. " makes no sense whatsoever. B can't counter the spell until A casts it.

Comment: @Matt, "When A doesn't counter it B then takes it back so he can instead cast x." This would not be legal. Again, noone's taking anything back, so that simply does not apply to this conversation.

Comment: Anyway, whoever's right, the outcome is the same in the OP's scenario. The attacker has the option of casting his/her Giant Growth before, in response to, or after the Lightning Bolt.

Comment: @ikegami When you say you are going to cast something and your opponent says something along the lines of "okay" that means they agreed to let it resolve. If you then don't cast it you have violated a rule (most likely a player communication rule)

Comment: @Matt, No it's not. You can't accept a spell resolving before he even states targets and taps the mana! Now, if he does that, he's playing out of turn, and the attacker can tell the attacker to wait, or allow it to happen. No shortcut involved there either.

Answer (score 1):

In a friendly game with someone just learning the game, I would let him take the Lightning Bolt back.

But if it's a tournament situation, and he did not wait for you to say "done" "go" "no fast effects" "moving to damage" or something similar, you're well within your rights to respond to the Lightning Bolt with a Giant Growth. *(I took a look at section 4.2 Tournament Shortcuts of the [MtG Tournament Rules](http://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Tournament_Rules_PDF1.pdf), and I didn't find anything specifically saying taking advantage of information due to skipping of priority was illegal.)*

Comment: Actually, saying "wait, I had priority" and doing nothing should not be done in a tournament. You can't request priority and then do nothing: _tournament rules 4.2: A player may not request priority and take no action with it. If a player decides he or she does not wish to do 
anything, the request is nullified and priority is returned to the player that originally had it._

Comment: @Pablo I think you're right and I'll strike that part of the answer. There's no need to go through the ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse actions until the game is in a legal state. He should not be able to play the spell until you pass priority. I have not been able to find anything regarding you using the information gleaned from his misplay. It is probably not stated anywhere, but is an ethical decision based on your setting.

In a tournament setting, your opponent might even receive punishment. See section 2.5 Gamplay Error - Game rule violation http://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Infraction_Procedure_Guide_PDF1.pdf

> If the error was discovered within a time frame in which a player
>   could reasonably be expected to notice the error and the situation is
>   simple enough to safely back up without too much disruption to the
>   course of the game, the judge may get permission from the Head Judge
>   to back up the game to the point of the error. Each action taken is
>   undone until the game reaches the point immediately prior to the
>   error. Cards incorrectly placed in hand are returned to the location
>   in the zone from which they were moved (if the identity of the
>   incorrectly drawn card is not known to all players, a random card is
>   returned instead). Once the game is backed up, it continues from that
>   point.

However is it not a good idea to try and rely on this as a meta strategy. Doing so can be considered fraud. http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/article.asp?ID=10794

Comment: If players had to pass priority explicity always, the games would be boring and too long. There is no gamepley error here, this is just a shortcut.

Comment: the question is worded in a way to make it sound as if it is not a shortcut: `my opponent forgets that I have priority...`

Comment: Rules knowledge (knowing if your opponent has priority in that situation) doesn't make an action a infraction or not. Under that premise, the same situation would be an infraction for an inexperienced player, but not for a veteran player.

Comment: @Colin I don't think you can know if your opponent forget you have priority or if your opponent is suggesting a shortcut where you pass priority.